# Scala's TreeSet vs Java's TreeSet - poll?

Tags: java, scala, priority-queue, scala-collections, treeset

If I want to remove the highest entry in `log(n)` time in Java's `TreeSet`, I use `treeSet.pollFirst()` - what is the equivalent for Scala's `mutable.TreeSet` class?

Anyway, what I really want is a heap-like priority queue data structure that lets me `removeMax`, `add` and `updatePriority` in logarithmic time. I looked at the Scala collections library and I am confused - while `mutable.PriorityQueue` lets me `deque` (i.e. `removeMax`) in logarithmic time - it provides no way to update priority in log time (I would have to hackily scan and remove item and re-add in linear time). Similarly `mutable.TreeSet` would let me update priority in logarithmic time (by hackily deleting and re-adding) but it does not have a `removeMax` (i.e. `pollFirst`) operation. What collections container should I use? Please do not refer me to external dependencies.

Comment: How are you thinking `updatePriority` would work with Java's `TreeSet`?

Comment: Easy (assuming you defined an external comparator by overriding the TreeSet with an anonymous class). You simply delete and add the node. Look at my example. Look at line 19 and line 33-36 of here: https://github.com/pathikrit/scalgos/blob/master/temp/SandBox/AStar.java

Comment: Right, makes sense.  You should remove the node before you update it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `head` and `last` methods in the `immutable.TreeSet`, which are `O(log n)`.
The same methods exist in `mutable.TreeSet`, but have not been overridden to provide better efficiency and amortized time (in Scala 2.10). The `head` method will be logarithmic, but may instantiate an iterator when doing so. The `last` method will actually traverse it, having linear complexity. The good news is that you can control what is smallest or largest with a custom `Ordering` - and easily obtain it from an existing `Ordering` by calling `Ordering.reverse`.

If you need to remove that element, simply use `-=`. You can create your own implicit value class to piggy back the method `pollFirst` on the tree set.

```
implicit class MyExtensions[T](ts: mutable.TreeSet[T]) extends AnyVal {
  def pollFirst(): T = {
    val elem = ts.head
    ts -= elem
    elem
  }
}
```

Comment: The head and last are equivalent to `peekFirst` and `peekLast` - what I want is **`poll`**

Comment: After identifying any element in a `TreeSet`, it is trivial to remove it with `-=`.

Comment: Ah, ok, but that is considerably uglier than simple `pollLast`

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just a suggestion :) remember that you can access Java libraries from scala (well, if you compile to the JVM :) so if Java's TreeSet works for you, use it :)

You can also clarify your requirements; what would be the parameters to your updatePriority method ? whose priority you trying to update ?